# Position of subview in UIScrollview on zoom

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, coordinates

I have UIScrollView with image on background, which can zoom in and out. I've also added subview with image inside scrollview. I've added it on `[50,50]` coordinates.

But when I zoom UIScrollView, second image moved from it position (looks like real coordinates mess with scrollview zoom somehow). How to keep second on its place (visually) when I zoom?

[before zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vplr4.jpg)
[after zoom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HvgSM.png)

Comment: If you want the second image to be kept in place on screen when the scrollview zooms you can't make it a child of the scrollview.  You would have to make it a sibling, but on top, of the scroll view.  Add the second image as a child of `scrollview.superview`.

Comment: But I want it to be scrolled with moving scrollview content. I want red pin image be sticked to some place on bg image not depending on zoom. If I put second image out of scroll view, then it will not move with scroll on move.

Comment: If that is the case, then you are either going to have to use 2 scrollviews (one for zooming and one for scrolling) or use delegate methods of the scrollview to find when zooming or panning and adjust the position and scale of the second image.  That is quite difficult due to animations and inertia, but it is possible.  I had to do that with one of my projects and it took quite a while to get everything smooth.